# Adwords - Approved banner won't display

Tags: google-ads-api

I started my first Adwords text campaign few weeks ago and everything looked ok. I get 20-30 visitors a day for about 3 euros per day.
Now I added banner add, they approved it, but it won't display as you can see on the screenshot. I paused the text ad and I raised the bid to 200%, but it didn't help. Do you know how to get the banner work?
Thank you.

[image: adwords campaign]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create two separate campaigns:
Search Network only for text ads
Display Network only for banners

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2567043?hl=en

Also, create multiple banners (horizontal, vertical, square, etc. - at least 5-6 of them) with the same content but different dimensions, sometimes a banner does not display simply because it doesn't fit anywhere on the website.